# Excel (.xlsx) write not working using java

Tags: java, excel, nullpointerexception, apache-poi, office-2016

I am unable to update Excel file(.xlsx) using my java code. can u please let me know where I am making mistake.  It throws a `NullPointerException`. Using POI Apache jars.Using Office 2016 for Excel

```
public class test_extra1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //excel code
        File src=new File("C:\\test.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
        XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sh1= wb.getSheetAt(0);

        String[] field_name = {"field1","field2"};

        String isChecked ="Checked",temp;

        int i;
        for(i=0;i<2;i++){

            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println("Checkbox not checked--"+isChecked);
            temp = field_name[i];
            System.out.println("temp----"+temp);
            //error comes at below line
            sh1.getRow(i+1).getCell(i+3).setCellValue("No");
            sh1.getRow(i+1).createCell(i+3).setCellValue("No");
            sh1.getRow(i+1).createCell(i+2).setCellValue(temp);

        }
        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test1.xlsx"));
        wb.write(fout);
        fout.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Where does it trow the exception?

Comment: Do all the rows and cells you're using already exist? What happens if you check + create if missing?

Comment: @Axel:it shows exception at line "sh1.getRow(i+1).getCell(i+3).setCellValue("No");"

Comment: @Gagravarr, as of now i am using new sheets so that is not the issue.

Comment: If you're using a new sheet, then it won't have any rows or cells! Sounds exactly like your issue...